# IOS 6 and NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, nsdateformatter

Here is the code:

```
NSString * str = @"2012-11-23Fri09:00:00+0100";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale= [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddEEEHH:mm:ssZ"];

NSDate *result = [formatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"str :%@ -- NSDate :%@", str, result);
```

and here is the output:

```
str :2012-11-23Fri09:00:00+0100 -- NSDate :1999-12-31 08:00:00 +0000
```

Why the `NSDate` is wrong?

Comment: I tried your code on iPhone 5.0 simulator and works fine, on iPhone 6.0 simulator it fails. It could be a bug, you have to send your code in the Apple Developer forum

Comment: This definitely a bug with iOS 6. If we remove that "Fri" and "EEE" from there, it works fine. Some bug when day name comes in the middle of the date.

Answer (score 1):

See this Link this might help you,

[Formatters in OS X v10.8 and iOS 6.0](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

[Formatters in iOS 5.0-5.1](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

thanks,

Naveen Shan