# Why won't NSDateFormatter parse this date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm having trouble getting NSDateFormatter to recognise this date that I am passing in. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the weekday, but I can't figure it out.

```
NSString *testDate = @"20130412 Friday";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
df.dateFormat = @"yyyyMMdd cccc";
NSDate *result = [df dateFromString:testDate];
NSLog(@"test: %@, result: %@", testDate, result);
```

This will give me a resulting date of 1999-12-30.  I have tried eeee and EEEE in the weekday, but it doesn't help. Removing the weekday seems to work, but doesn't explain what is wrong with my date format.

Comment: It gives me 2013-04-10 17:07:27.163 Memory[1409:f803] test: 20130412 Friday, result: 2013-04-12 06:00:00 +0000

Comment: Just a guess: have you tried putting *6* c's there instead of four?

Comment: 6 cs makes no difference. Strange that HalR gets a different result - I'm using XCode 4.6 and building with latest ios sdk. Are you also?

Comment: This looks to be a similar problem. It would appear that weekday introduces some issues in iOS 6. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583481/ios-6-and-nsdateformatter

Comment: Have you looked at the docs at http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns and verified the proper format specifier you should be using for a non-stand-alone weekday (hint, it's not 'c')?

Comment: sure, as mentioned earlier, I've also tried eeee and EEEE but that doesn't help

Comment: @Dan My bad, I didn't read far enough into your question. Sorry. I reported a bug to Apple a month ago with issues related to weekday formats under iOS 6. It only works if the weekday part is at the start of the string. Anywhere else results in a problem parsing the string.

Comment: Why not just ignore the weekday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why the weekday is there. It creates the possibility of an inconsistent date. What would you expect of "20130412 Tuesday"? (note for future readers: 20130412 is in fact a Friday) I checked http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime and could find no prohibition on adding the day of the week, but it seems like a bad idea to me.

However, the NSDateFormatter does not appear to be behaving correctly. I tested on iOS 6.1 simulator and on OS X 10.8.3, and got the same results on both platforms. I even expanded a bit, adding

```
id longResult;
NSError *error;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, testDate.length);
if (![df getObjectValue:&longResult forString:testDate range:&range error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@ reason:%@", error.localizedDescription, error.localizedFailureReason );
}

NSLog(@"result: %@", longResult);
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRange(range));
```

below your code and producing

```
2013-04-10 16:45:27.921 date formatter fun ios[47350:c07] test: 20130412 Friday, result: 1999-12-31 07:00:00 +0000
2013-04-10 16:45:27.922 date formatter fun ios[47350:c07] result: 1999-12-31 07:00:00 +0000
2013-04-10 16:45:27.922 date formatter fun ios[47350:c07] {0, 15}
```

It's attempting to parse, returning a YES (successful parse), yet putting the wrong answer into the result.