# NSString convert to NSDate, very weird result

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want convert a date string to NSDate, here is the code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd EEE HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2013-04-11 Thu 09:00:00"];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

However, it prints `1999-12-30 09:00:00 +0000`. So weird, can anybody help me, thank you!

Comment: It's known bug in iOS 6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583481/ios-6-and-nsdateformatter

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOS 6 and NSDateFormatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583481/ios-6-and-nsdateformatter)